# Apply a sum to each cell for a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want a way to apply a sum to each cell of a column - that runs on the cell to the left of it:

Example:

[image]

I need the red box to take the value from the cell on its left and devide it by an amount.

I know I can do this with =sum(B4 * 0.053)

[image]

But I want to apply this formula to every cell on the column for the one on the left of it - as I don't know how many there will be in total.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must use `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B4:B*0.053)
```

And to bypass empty lines, I suggest adding `IF`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4:B="","",B4:B*0.053))
```